# Apply last edits in netplan with no service

Tags: services, netplan, interface

On my virtual computer I hace two NICs. Internet connection works fine, thanks to network-bridge.
Now, I edited my `/etc/netplan/01-netcf...yaml`. Since I have no network services as `network-manager` or `networking` I always have to reboot whole computer, to apply the changes. (I cannot restart any service). Is there any way to avoid restarting whole PC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `sudo netplan apply` to apply the configuration changes to the running system.